# How can I correctly change my public IP in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, configuration

I have a Ubuntu droplet in Digital Ocean and a Floating IP. I want all the requests from that droplet to be done using the Floating IP.

I can achieve this using if I change the IP address in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml and run sudo netplan apply. Then, if I do curl ifconfig.me I get the correct IP address.

However, when I reboot the machine it becomes inaccessible. I need to log in through the console, change the IP back to the public IP of the Droplet, run sudo netplan apply. Then network becomes available. After that I can switch back to the floating IP and everything works.

How can I do this change properly, so it's permanent and survives a reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating IPs are Routed to the assigned droplet's IP, you'd need to either assign it to the interface secondary or localhost.

Add a new file, ex. `/etc/netplan/00-floatip.yaml` or anything that's alphabetically before `50-cloud-init.yaml` (and make sure it's yaml not yml)

configure it as something like:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    lo:
      addresses:
        - 127.0.0.1/8
        - 192.0.2.0/32
```

where 192.0.2.0 is your float ip

Note, if you want OUTBOUND traffic to use your float IP by default, look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/send-outbound-traffic-over-floating-ip

which isn't the intended use for Float IPs, float IPs are for inbound traffic.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm just left with my original IP as public IP.

Comment: "Doesn't work" meaning what, are you trying to hit the droplet or just trying to curl ifconfig.me

what about `curl --interface 192.0.2.0 ifconfig.me`

Comment: It means I run `curl ifconfig.me` and get the standard public IP, not the floating IP. The idea is that all outgoing requests will go through the floating IP after the configuration change.

Comment: I followed the link you posted and it works! Thank you!